# DataGridComboBoxColumn does not display SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel (pseudo code for its structure):

```
class ViewModel
{
    public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}
enum Type
{
    Type1,
    Type2, ....
}
class Package
{
    public Type PackageType { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I bind my DataGrid with the property Packages of the ViewModel.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Types}}"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding PackageType, Mode=TwoWay}">
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

This is how I define Resource Types:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Types">
        <CollectionViewSource.Source>
            <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="s:Type"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </CollectionViewSource.Source>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

DataGridComboBoxColumn can show the ComboBox. However, it does not show the value of the Package.PackageType. It behaves like the binding is only one way to source. When I update the ComboBox, the object is updated. The other way does not work.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `SelectedValueBinding` instead of `SelectedItemBinding`

Comment: @Shoe Doesn't work and the combo box loses value right after I change it.

Comment: You might try a `DataTemplateColumn` and see if a regular combobox will take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the answer. I did some more research. Turn out, the problem is when I define `ObjectDataProvider`. I need to use `MethodName="GetValues"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Package needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  If your list of Packages might change, use ObservableCollection instead.  It wouldn't hurt to make the view model implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Package : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Type packageType;

    public Type PackageType 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.packageType;
        } 

        set
        {
            if (this.packageType != value)
            {
                this.packageType = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("PackageType")
            }
        }
    }

    // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the answer. I did some more research. Turn out, the problem is when I define ObjectDataProvider. I need to use MethodName="GetValues" instead